# ASP.NET MVC Web app redirecting to localhost after being published and authenticated

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a simple MVC Web App with authentication using Azure Active Directory for authentication. I used the connected services wizard in Visual Studio 2017 to do this for me. My problem currently is that everything works perfectly on my local machine and I am able to login, be redirected to the index page of the web app and also able to log out. However, when I publish this app, I am get redirected to localhost:https://localhost:44389/ instead of the Web App's index page.

1. Changed the PostLogoutRedirectUri in the app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication() method in Startup.Auth.cs to point to:

"https://CU-kvtest.azurewebsites.net/"

This didn't work and still went to localhost.

2.Changed the PostLogoutRedirectUri in the Web.Config file to point to "https://CU-kvtest.azurewebsites.net/". That didn't work either and still went to localhost

3. Went to the Azure portal and went to the Azure Active Directory called ContosoUniversity2 (That is the name of the directory I'm using) and changed the redirectURI to "https://CU-kvtest.azurewebsites.net/" and that started causing other issues. I have a keyvault set up that fetches my connectionString securely and now this issue starts:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Dd1.jpg

So this attempt was also a bust.

4. Then I went to my published App service in Azure portal and added two app settings:

ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri= "https://CU-kvtest.azurewebsites.net/"
PostLogoutRedirectUri="https://CU-kvtest.azurewebsites.net/"

That didn't work either and would just point me to localhost again.

I'm really lost as to what else I could do. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong...

Startup.Auth.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IdentityModel.Claims;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Owin;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private static string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private static string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private static string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
        private static string postLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"];

        public static readonly string Authority = aadInstance + tenantId;

        // This is the resource ID of the AAD Graph API.  We'll need this to request a token to call the Graph API.
        string graphResourceId = "https://graph.windows.net/";

        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = clientId,
                    Authority = Authority,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://CU-kvtest.azurewebsites.net/",

                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
                    {
                        // If there is a code in the OpenID Connect response, redeem it for an access token and refresh token, and store those away.
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = (context) =>
                        {
                            var code = context.Code;
                            ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
                            string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
                            AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(Authority, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
                            return authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                               code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, graphResourceId);
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    }
}
```

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />


  <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  <section name="configBuilders" type="System.Configuration.ConfigurationBuildersSection, System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" restartOnExternalChanges="false" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <configBuilders>
    <builders>
    <add name="AzureKeyVault" vaultName="kv-talha-final" type="Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.AzureKeyVaultConfigBuilder, Microsoft.Configuration.ConfigurationBuilders.Azure, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" /></builders>
  </configBuilders>

  <!--<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=ContosoUniversity2;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>-->
  <!--Azure connection string-->
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SchoolContext" connectionString="thisdoesntmatter" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-ContosoUniversity-bb3d24b7-855d-4be5-b5ee-a97316af18f2.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-ContosoUniversity-bb3d24b7-855d-4be5-b5ee-a97316af18f2;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="connectionString" value="dummy" />

    <!--This is the domain called ContosoUniversity2-->
    <add key="ida:ClientId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="ida:AADInstance" value="https://login.microsoftonline.com/" />
    <add key="ida:ClientSecret" value="XXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="ida:Domain" value="mtalha97hotmail.onmicrosoft.com" />
    <!--The tenant is ContosoUniversity2-->
    <add key="ida:TenantId" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
    <add key="ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri" value="dummy" />
  </appSettings>
  <!--
    For a description of web.config changes see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=235367.

    The following attributes can be set on the <httpRuntime> tag.
      <system.Web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
      </system.Web>
  -->


</configuration>
```

AccountController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public void SignIn()
        {
            // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/" },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
        }

        public void SignOut()
        {
            string callbackUrl = Url.Action("SignOutCallback", "Account", routeValues: null, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);

            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = callbackUrl },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        public ActionResult SignOutCallback()
        {
            if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // Redirect to home page if the user is authenticated.
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

UserProfileController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect;
using ContosoUniversity.Models;

namespace ContosoUniversity.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class UserProfileController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
        private string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
        private string appKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
        private string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
        private string graphResourceID = "https://graph.windows.net/";

        // GET: UserProfile
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;
            try
            {
                Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(graphResourceID);
                Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri, tenantID);
                ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                      async () => await GetTokenForApplication());

                // Use the token for querying the graph to get the user details

                var result = await activeDirectoryClient.Users
                    .Where(u => u.ObjectId.Equals(userObjectID))
                    .ExecuteAsync();
                IUser user = result.CurrentPage.ToList().First();

                return View(user);
            }
            catch (AdalException)
            {
                // Return to error page.
                return View("Error");
            }
            // If the above failed, the user needs to explicitly re-authenticate for the app to obtain the required token
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("Relogin");
            }
        }

        public void RefreshSession()
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/UserProfile" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }

        public async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
        {
            string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
            string tenantID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid").Value;
            string userObjectID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value;

            // Get a token for the Graph without triggering any user interaction (from the cache, via multi-resource refresh token, etc)
            ClientCredential clientcred = new ClientCredential(clientId, appKey);
            // Initialize AuthenticationContext with the token cache of the currently signed in user, as kept in the app's database
            AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(aadInstance + tenantID, new ADALTokenCache(signedInUserID));
            AuthenticationResult authenticationResult = await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(graphResourceID, clientcred, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
            return authenticationResult.AccessToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you facing this problem only after logout? Is the login flow works fine? Did you try searching term `localhost` in the entire solution code? Did you find any?

Comment: No I am facing the problem as soon as I try to log in to the website. The login flow works fine on local and I am able to log in and successfully navigate the website. The localhost is in PostLogoutRedirectUri and I changed that based on the suggested answer provided below but now I'm getting this error: https://imgur.com/a/8L9VU9s

Answer (score 1):

1. Change the PostLogoutRedirectUri to your web app site url in web.config file.

[image]

2. Configure your AAD application. Change the redirect url to your web app site url.

[image]

3. Rebuild and republish your web application.
4. Restart your web app on Azure portal.

Comment: Seem to be getting this error after I do that: https://imgur.com/a/8L9VU9s

Comment: Any more suggestions? Still stuck here :(

Comment: @tt1997 I am not sure. It seems to be a different problem now. Based on the description, you may use managed identity to get a secret from Azure Key Vault in application settings.  You may refer to this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Comment: I used that initially to configure my KeyVault and it worked perfectly. I had specified my KeyVault reference in my connectionString part in the azure portal for app settings. I don't understand why I'm getting that error again if it was working earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Not using Azure but I had a similar problem on my VPS.  My issue turned out to be I had set the following in the _Layout partial view:

```
<BASE href=http://localhost:52549>
```

changing local host to to my application path fixed it